# How to compile SCSS correctly using Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, sass

I'm having a hard time understanding how to compile a child theme in Wordpress. My main theme compiles using compass into an app.css file. I've created the standard style.css in a child theme folder. Wordpress recognises this. I've created a scss file inside the child theme folder, I've then added it to the import list in the app.scss file in my main theme. Compass doesn't throw an error when trying t import but Compass isn't recognising changes in the child theme scss file though. Is this the correct set up? I've put the import after my general variables file so I can overwrite the variables in the child theme.

Comment: The correct thing to do would be to compile a new CSS file from within the child theme, and import the parent theme SASS files.

Comment: Another question: What's the point of using a child theme if you are going to modify the parent theme **app.scss** anyway?

Comment: So to move the app.scss file into the child theme, and import all the scss files from the main theme? Im wanting to use the child theme to override the variables created by the main theme to change the colour etc of the site. As this will be rolling out across multiple sites.

Comment: No, I'm saying to copy everything into the child theme, and just work from the child theme.

Comment: I want to be able to add more variables and styling into the main theme folder and roll this out to all the sites. So for instance create a new block or section